# Parsing url in javascript or angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parsing, url

I'm trying to parse url in javascript, I found the following way:

```
var getLocation = function(href) {
    var l = document.createElement("a");
    l.href = href;
    return l;
};
var l = getLocation("http://example.com:3000/path");
var host = l.host; // example.com
var port = l.port; // 3000
```

But I faced a problem if these locations:

```
http://TLVS0015:3000/cti/YTest // the parse found the port, but its not found the host

http://ctmwe:80/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx // the parse found the host, but don't found the port
```

Is there any other way to do the parse?

Comment: Try doing `l.hostname`

Comment: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/parsing-urls-with-the-dom/

Comment: IF you have the url already, wouldn't you be better to split() and get the components? (Rather then create an object I mean) If there any perf benefits of doing it this way rather then using strings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't need to support Internet Explorer (http://caniuse.com/#feat=url), use `URL`. Use `hostname` instead of `host`.

```
> new URL("http://TLVS0015:3000/cti/YTest").hostname
tlvs0015
```

The port is 80. Port 80 is default, so it is redundant, hence `""`.

```
> new URL("http://ctmwe:80/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx").port
""

port = URL.port === "" ? 80 : URL.port
```

For more information on `URL()`, [consult the MDN API documents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL.URL).

**Note**: as of July 2017, `URL` *is not supported by Internet Explorer 11*: http://caniuse.com/#feat=url

Comment: Note that `URL` is is an experimental feature that is not supported in Internet Explorer as of April 2015.

Comment: And continues to be as of July 2016

Comment: March 2017 - looks like it was never supported in IE, but it's in Edge 14 and 15. http://caniuse.com/#feat=url

Answer (score 14):

Source:- https://gist.github.com/jlong/2428561

```
var parser = document.createElement('a');
parser.href = "http://example.com:3000/pathname/?search=test#hash";

parser.protocol; // => "http:"
parser.hostname; // => "example.com"
parser.port;     // => "3000"
parser.pathname; // => "/pathname/"
parser.search;   // => "?search=test"
parser.hash;     // => "#hash"
parser.host;     // => "example.com:3000"
```